# how to set and take in a integer to/from a file in java

Tags: java, integer, save

So this is a very simple question. I have been trying to research it, and yes I have slightly found some answers but i can't find out how it works so i have come to this.

I am making a simple game in java (pong) and their is a high score integer that i would like to be able save and load from a file (I have heard a lot about using a txt file so probably that, but i have also heard about using a xml i believe is what it is, but i did not look into that as much). How exactly do i program this?

Thank you to all who answer.

PS

I have looked into this code but I don't understand how it's workings

```
String strFilePath = "C://FileIO//WriteInt.txt";

try {
  //create FileOutputStream object
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);


  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

  int i = 100;

  dos.writeInt(i);

  dos.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("IOException : " + e);
}
```

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far? Have you attempted to write any code? If so, please post it. (Just keep it short.) If not, why not?

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/write_to_textfile.html

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=386

Answer (score 2):

The most simplest way is to create a file, i.e.

write the score to a file, e.g.

```
String user = "John";
int score = 100;
f = new BufferedWriter(new FileReader(filepath));
f.write(user + "=" + score); // assuming "=" is not inside the user name
f.close();
```

then read from the file when you need it, e.g.

```
f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
String line = f.readLine().trim();
String[] temp = line.split("="); // now temp is of the form ["John", "100"]
String user = temp[0];
int score = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
f.close();
```

Comment: Thanks ill see how this works seems a lot simpler then what i posted

Comment: No problem :) remember to put f.close() at the end, i forgot to put it before, just updated

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve this encoding the object into a file,but it wont be an xml, it will be a custom file that only your app will be able to open

```
 public void save(Integer ... integersToEncode){

       try{
         ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream (new File(/*yourFileName*/)));
         for(Integer encoding : integersToEncode)
             output.writeObject(encoding);

         output.close();

       }
       catch(Exception e){
         //What do you want to do if the program could not write the file
       }


    }
```

For reading

```
 public Integer[] read(int size){


    Integer[] objects = new Integer[size];
       try{
         ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream (new File(/*yourFileName*/)));
         for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
             objects[i] = (Integer)input.readObject();
        input.close();

       }
       catch(Exception e){
         //What do you want to do if the program could not write the file
       }

       return objects;
    }
```

Comment: I think serializing an entire object to store a single `int` value is a little extreme.

Comment: The thing is that he is serializing Integers, anyway you will alllways encode only the Integer and you wont have to parse it at reading time

Comment: question how will i access this then

Comment: @BaxterLopez I guess so. It just seems less elegant of a solution to me.

Comment: @Lifetake I updeted the awnswer.

Comment: @AndrewG as a .txt anyone will be able to edit it with any text processor so i thing this is the best way to do the file saving

Comment: @BaxterLopez Very true. It is a secure way of doing it. I guess you have a point. You win this time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were confused by the way the original code you posted was printing the char 'd' to the output file. This is the character's ASCII value, as you may know. The following modifications to your code make it work the way you were orginally looking at:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Game game = new Game();
        game.writeHighScore();

    }

    public void writeHighScore() throws IOException{

    String strFilePath = "C:/Users/User/workspace/HighScore.txt";   

    FileInputStream is = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;

    try
    {
      //create FileOutputStream object
        fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);

        dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

      int i = 100;

      dos.writeInt(i);

      System.out.println("New High Score saved");

      dos.close();

    // create file input stream
      is = new FileInputStream(strFilePath);

      // create new data input stream
      dis = new DataInputStream(is);

      // available stream to be read
      while(dis.available()>0)
      {
         // read four bytes from data input, return int
         int k = dis.readInt();

         // print int
         System.out.print(k+" ");
      }
   }catch(Exception e){
      // if any error occurs
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{

      // releases all system resources from the streams
      if(is!=null)
         is.close();
      if(dis!=null)
         dis.close();
    if(fos!=null)
         fos.close();
    if(dos!=null)
         dos.close();
   }
}

}
```